# Sharing an ADO Connection across a DLL boundary

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-xe

We would like to share an ADOConnection across a DLL boundary (Delphi to Delphi at the moment, though could also be C# to Delphi in the near future).

As we would like the flexibility to call the DLL from c# in future, we were hoping to be able to define the DLL call using _Connection as a parameter. Something like:

```
procedure DoStuff (ADOConnection: _Connection)
var
  InnerConnection: TADOConnection;
begin
  InnerConnection := TADOConnection.create(nil);
  try
    InnerConnection.ConnectionObject := ADOConnection;
    DoMoreStuff(InnerConnection);
  finally
    InnerConnection.free;
  end;
end;
```

Unfortunately, the TADOConnection destructor code closes the connection passed into it, which is an unwanted side-effect. Adding

```
InnerConnection.ConnectionObject := nil
```

prior to the free doesn't do anything, as it's caught by

```
if Assigned(Value) = nil
```

in TADOConnection.SetConnectionObject, which results in the call not doing anything.

Is there a better way of achieving this? Passing the connection string is an alternative, but would mean that we would have to deal with username/password issues and encryption across the boundary. Passing the TADOConnection is another option, but that prevents calling from other languages.

Edit: For clarity, the Username/Password of the original TADOConnection object is set using the .Open routine, so these details aren't in the connection string (in fact, the wrong username is usually stored, as it's the name used to 'test connection' in the MS UDL editor)

Comment: Just a thought: do you have the possibility of transferring your Ado data to a TClientDataSet?  Reason I ask is that CDS data is easy to transfer across DLL boundaries as a variant.

Comment: @TLama The Connection object isn't freed, it's just closed

Comment: @MartynA possibly, but not without a big re-work. We're trying to do this as a quick patch to extract existing code into a DLL for dealing with third-party libraries that won't compile in later versions of Delphi. Restructuring to use a ClientDataset will require a lot of splitting logic across the DLL boundary

Comment: How about: `InnerConnection.ConnectionString := ADOConnection.ConnectionString`?

Comment: @kobik That's pretty much the same as just passing the connection string. It also doesn't contain the password, which would need passing in encrypted form. Not impossible, but not ideal

Comment: @MattAllwood, "It also doesn't contain the password" why do you think so?

Comment: @kobik 'cos I can inspect the string in debug :-)

Comment: @MattAllwood, (after your edit) You can't see the password because you are using `Persist Security Info=False` (default) not because you use `.Open` with user ID/password

Comment: @kobik so it does - I only thought that it kept username/password info entered at design time. Still, that option is pretty much the same as passing the connection string and there's big red flags in the documentation about persisting security so I'd prefer to keep using the open _connection if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
  type TInit_StFattDLL = procedure( var DataBase:TAdoConnection);
  var  Init_StFattDLL:TInit_StFattDll;
```

The caller is:

```
Function ConnectDll():Boolean;
var
  handleDll:THandle;

begin
    handleDll := LoadLibrary('mydll.DLL');
    @Init_StFattDLL := GetProcAddress(handleDll , 'myConnectFunction');

      if @Init_StFattDLL <> nil then   
        begin
          Init_StFattDLL(ADOConnection1);
          result:=true;
         end
      else
         result:=false;
end;
```

into the the dll put the following:

in the project file put the exports:

```
Exports myConnectFunction;
```

global section:

```
var Database:TAdoConnection;
```

the exported procedure is the following:

```
procedure myConnectFunction( var MyDataBase:TAdoConnection);export;
begin
   Database:=MyDataBase;
end
```

Comment: Isn't this just passing the TADOConnection object across the DLL boundary? As I said in the question, it's an option, but makes the resultant dll Delphi-only.

Comment: Yes, in this way you pass the pointer of the Adoconnection class.
Anyway I'm sorry. My mind stopped to read your question at "Delphi to Delphi at the moment" ;)